# Rails: Get rid of default value using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created an activeRecord that added a default value to a MYSQL table column using :default => 1000

I want to get rid of this default value now. How do I do so? I tried :default => nil to no avail.

Comment: Are you looking to update the DB schema (which that should do) or to update the data in the table?

Comment: I am looking to update the DB schema so the column will have no default.. Ah wait, I needed to refresh the table schema. It works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a migration file

```
class RemoveDefaultValueOfKarmaInUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_column :users, :karma, :integer, :default => nil
  end

  def self.down
    change_column :users, :karma, :integer, :default => 1000
  end
end
```